# Get the first index in a custom "indexOf" function in Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, string, dictionary

I'm learning Swift and I got this challenge in order to improve in my studying with `extensions`

> Create a custom "indexOf" function that returns the first index of the occurrence in a given String. Input can be mixed

So the above translates to:

```
Text: "Hello, world"
Phrase: "lol"
Output: 2
```

Another example would be:

```
Text: "Hello, playground"
Phrase: " pal,ol"
Output: 2
```

#### Explanation

The first example when the `phrase` is permuted can take the following values (twice each because of repeated L):

```
llo
oll
lol
```

So one of the permutations is actually part of `Hello` word, starting at index 2.

Same goes with the second example, it starts with a space, has a `ol` at the end which are actually part of `lo` on the first word, then it has `pal` which is a permutation of `pla`.

I've had different ways to approach this problem:

1. Doing all the permutations per phrase given and look for each of them oh the original text, however the problems I find with this approach are that the number of permutations is given by `N!` where `N` is the number of letters in the phrase which might easily run out of memory.
2. Looking for each letter and store all their positions in the original text inside a `Dictionary [Character : [Int]]`, then convert the values to an array of arrays of Integers (`[[Int]]`) so that we can sort the values inside and be able to compare them. This is the approach I'm using as it seems like a reasonable solution, however I'm stuck at how to compare the values in the array or the dictionary against the other ones...

For example, I'm using the following code:

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"

extension String {
    func customIndexOf(subword: String) -> Int {
        var lettersDictionary: [Character : [Int]] = [ : ]
        var listOfIndexes: [[Int]] = []

        for letter in subword {
            lettersDictionary[letter] = findAllOccurrencesBy(letter: letter)
        }

        for (_, v) in lettersDictionary {
            listOfIndexes.append(v)
        }

        print(listOfIndexes)

        return -1
    }

    private func findAllOccurrencesBy(letter: Character) -> [Int] {
        var indexes = [Int]()
        var searchStartIndex = self.startIndex

        while searchStartIndex < self.endIndex,
            let range = self.range(of: String(letter), range: searchStartIndex..<self.endIndex),
            !range.isEmpty
        {
            let index = distance(from: self.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
            indexes.append(index)
            searchStartIndex = range.upperBound
        }

        return indexes
    }

    private func compareIndexes(listOfIndexes: [[Int]]) {

    }
}

print (str.customIndexOf(subword: "play"))
```

Which gives me the following output as of now:

```
[[7], [9], [10], [2, 3, 8]]
-1
```

This should return `7` because that's where `p` of `playground` is located, so I want to loop through each of the arrays and compare them against all of the other ones. If the difference between them is 1, it means the letters are all consecutive (which is what we want), if they are, then we return the lowest index, otherwise if there's a difference of 2+ among the letters we return -1.

How do I iterate over all the arrays and look for that difference among the indexes? Or is there any easier way to approach this problem?

Comment: u should probably return some value of listOfIndexes instead of -1, i guess sort of first occurrence u want to do.

Comment: Well that -1 is just so that the compiler doesn't complain about missing return statement. It will actually return the lowest index found after `compareIndexes` has been called, or `-1` if it finishes earlier or there's a difference of 2+ among the values in the lists. That's why I kept it as `-1` for now... @Vanya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax with extensions is fine, so you need improvement on your algorithm logic. Break this down into two simpler problems: checking for a string within a substring, and checking if a string matches permutations of a string

What if we could compare two strings regardless of order instead of checking all permutations? If we could create a function that could return true as long as two strings had the same occurrence of letters, we wouldn't need all the permutations. Let's call this function funA(String) -> Bool

We could then call that function on a moving index within the String we're checking against (or in the case of an extension, self)

Example:

Text: Hello there
Phrase: lol
Starting index: 0, length: 3

```
funA(Hel) = false  
funA(ell) = false  
funA(llo) = true
```

return 2, which is the current starting index

Comment: Gotcha! Let me try to create this approach in code... never thought of this way :)

Comment: Good luck :) When it comes to creating an algorithm, always try to see what your bottleneck is (in this case, having to create all the permutations) and see if you can break that down into an individual problem and come up with a simpler solution for it

Comment: Yeah I appreciate the help, I'm not that bad at algorithms but I needed another perspective :)